# Strange jagged display issue

Tags: lubuntu, display

Fresh instal of Lubuntu 19.10. Yet when I start it up it works just fine but the display is corrupted. It's almost as if every other line of the display is off by one pixel. I tried installing Mint in the past and I had this same issue.

PC otherwise runs Win10 just fine without this graphicsl issue. Any suggestions?

Here is a picture of my screen:
[My screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKYrm.jpg)

```
    lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

[And another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FAqy.jpg)
I added this to show the jagged effect has to do with the monitor and not software

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to describe (or what in picture I should look at)   (*You've also tagged Mint which is off-topic on this site (that detail can be useful as background, but it's off-topic - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic*)

Comment: Well. I'm hoping to get a fix to the problem. Okay so there are 1080 horizontal pixels on a screen right? Well it's almost as if every second pixel is offset horizontally by one pixel. Making things appear jagged. (the [x] looks all weird for example)

Comment: Can you do a `sudo lshw -C video` (list-hardware of class=video) and edit and add (paste into) to your question (use {} code block to format). The only things I see could be camera related so I ignored. It could be your windows uses a different refresh rate so you could try changing that (use Monitor Settings - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html)

Comment: I added the code that showed up in my original post :) Along with a screenshot I took.

Comment: I can confirm it works just fine on another computer, but if there is any way I could fix it for my main computer that'd be nice :) And when I mentioned Mint I more meant ANY Linux on my main PC so far have had the same graphical issues. I think it may be the fact I have a HP All-In-One computer and may just be to proprietary. Lemme try to find it

Comment: https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c04738839

Comment: Id its any help. changing resolution AND refresh rate using xrandr -s and -r and even at the lowest res and highest refresh rate the issue persists. Very weird.. Sorry if I'm wasting your time.

Comment: Even with the second attached picture, I don't see your issue sorry. `lximage-qt` which Lubuntu uses to take screenshots allows you to add arrows, circles to your screenshot which may point out the area where you have an issue (highlighting where we should look); or you could try looking at this site from another box to ensure we can see it (*then maybe tell me I may need a *eye-check* if necessary*)